# When and where might kevent return errors?

Tags: c, kqueue

Invalid items in the change list (or with `EV_RECEIPT` set) will cause `kevent` to return results with the `EV_ERROR` flag set. What other condition results in that flag?

A Google search reveals that `EV_RECEIPT` support is related to "disambiguating error conditions;" I wonder when this edge case applies.

Is it safe to assume that errors from the change list will appear first in the event list, before actual events?

What if we only consider filters related to sockets?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a document that discusses kqueue **http://doc.geoffgarside.co.uk/kqueue/** and it makes reference to **http://doc.geoffgarside.co.uk/kqueue/files/kqerror.c** to see the possible errors. I am not familiar with this concept, but maybe you can figure it out from what is there.

Comment: Thanks, but this is only general information, similar to other resources like the manpage. Passing an empty eventlist, such as for one-time configuration which is aborted upon an invalid item error, is a specific use-case which avoids `EV_ERROR` entirely.